# Failed to serialize arguments with Electron in Renderer with win.webContents.send

Tags: node.js, electron

I do have an sql query which return datasets. Now I want to send this via w*in.webContents.send* to the renderer, but I get the an exception: "Failed to serialize arguments" when I run the program.

```
ipcMain.on('get-all', (event) => {
  var docs = query();
  console.log(docs)
  win.webContents.send('paraset-get-all', docs);
})

async function query () {
  var dataarray=[];
  let pool = await sql.connect(MSSQLDBconfig.getConfig("configDB"));
  let data = await pool.request()
      .query('SELECT * FROM tbl_Parameter')
  for (let i=0;i<data.rowsAffected;i++){
      dataarray.push(data.recordset[i]);
  }
  pool.close;
  sql.close;
  return JSON.stringify(dataarray);
}
```

The console output shows all the expected datasets, but how can I transport this to the renderer to put it in a datagrid?

Comment: I think you dont have to stringify the array to pass using ipc message. can you specify show the output value you get in the console, in this current scenario and without the stringify function.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help you

```
query().then(data =>{
 win.webContents.send('paraset-get-all', data)
}.catch((err)=>{
 console.log(err)
}));
```